# Change tag on hover - replace image with text

Tags: jquery, html

I have an image with a value and I want to be able to hover over the image and change it to text (to show what the image means, because the image is rather small)

I've tried using `replaceWith` but that doesn't work when you stop hovering.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#apples").hover(function(){
            $(this).replaceWith("<span id=\"apples\">apples: 10</span>");
            }, function(){
            $(this).replaceWith("<span id=\"apples\"><img src=\"images/apples.png\" alt=\"apples\"/> 10</span>");
        });
    });
```

Hopefully I explained that correctly. I just want to switch out the image of an apple with the text that says apples when the user hovers over it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace the inner html of the element, otherwise the original element (which has a hover event listener) ceases to exist:

```
 $("#apples").hover(function(){
        $(this).html("apples: 10");
        }, function(){
        $(this).html("<img src=\"images/apples.png\" alt=\"apples\"/> 10");
 });
```